# Bundler: is bundle viz the only way to show the dependencies?

Tags: bundler

I don't have Graphviz on this machine and don't wish to install it, so an alternative, the terminal being preferred, would be good.

Bundler v1.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gemfile.lock shows dependencies:

```
view Gemfile.lock
```

e.g.

```
GEM
remote: http://rubygems.org/
specs:
  ZenTest (4.5.0)
  aaronh-chronic (0.3.9)
  abstract (1.0.0)
  actionmailer (3.0.19)
    actionpack (= 3.0.19)
    mail (~> 2.2.19)
  actionpack (3.0.19)
    activemodel (= 3.0.19)
    activesupport (= 3.0.19)
  ...
```